# How to add an authorization policy with multiple scopes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization, identityserver4

```
options.AddPolicy("Account", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountWrite", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.write"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountRead", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.read"));
```

How do you add an OR to a policy scope?

- "Account" policy when the scope is "account" (read, write and delete)
- "AccountWrite" policy when the scope is either "account" OR "account.write" (read and write)
- "AccountRead" policy when the scope is "account.read" (read only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can add multiple arguments to the RequireClaim statement. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationpolicybuilder.requireclaim?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationPolicyBuilder_RequireClaim_System_String_System_String___):

> **RequireClaim(String, String[])**
>
> ***claimType***
>       String
>
> The claim type required.
>
> ***allowedValues***
>       IEnumerable
>
> Values the claim must process *one or more* of for evaluation to
>   succeed.

In your case something like:

```
options.AddPolicy("Account", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account", "account.read", "account.write", "account.delete"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountWrite", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account", "account.write"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountRead", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account", "account.read"));
```

---

But this is a bit odd for scopes.

Having a scope means that a *client* is authorized to access the resource, regardless which user uses the client.

A scope marks a part of the resource that does a specific task, in other words, has certain functionality.

Assuming a CRUD AccountController:

1. You can authorize a *client* to access the entire controller, use the `account` scope in that case on top of the controller.
2. You can authorize the *client* per method, e.g. `account.read` the *Index* method, `account.write` the *Create* and *Update* methods and `account.delete` the *Delete* method. It's not likely that scopes can be mixed due to the difference in functionality.

Both can be fine, because it's the *user* that needs to be authorized to use the resource. The client takes the user to the resource and does the request on behalf of the user. But it makes no sense to combine both.

What would be the appropriate design for you?

Suppose you have an admin app, where the user is allowed to manage the account. The customer has its own app and wants to access the resource using that app, but you don't want to allow full management from that app.

In that case the *client* app from the customer should be allowed to request the `account.read` scope only. Because, if the user is allowed to manage the account, then you want to make sure that this is only possible using your app.

So you can 'normalize' the policies.

For 1.

```
options.AddPolicy("Account", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account"));
```

and for 2.

```
options.AddPolicy("AccountDelete", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.delete"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountWrite", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.write"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountRead", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.read"));
```

Come to think of it, based on the customer app as mentioned above, there is a third option:

3. You can authorize the *client* per method, e.g. `AccountRead` the *Index* method and `Account` for the other methods. Where `AccountRead` must include the account scope.

The policies would then look like:

```
// policy to allow client access to write and delete functionality
options.AddPolicy("Account", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account"));
// policy to allow client access to read functionality only
options.AddPolicy("AccountRead", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account", "account.read"));
```

The admin app only has to request the `account` scope, while the customer app can request the `account.read` scope.

Please note that the last part does not answer your original question but may answer the questions raised in the comments.

Comment: shouldnt it be like this?                 options.AddPolicy("Account", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account"));
                options.AddPolicy("AccountWrite", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account", "account.write"));
                options.AddPolicy("AccountRead", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account", "account.read"));

Comment: @001 It's just an example to demonstrate the possibilities. I'm not sure of how you designed it. In particular with the account scope and policy. I wouldn't use an account scope if I have an account.read, account.write and account.delete scope. Also the account policy is a bit 'strange'. I wouldn't protect functionality with an account policy, but rather replace this with AccountDelete, resulting in the policies: read, write, delete. Where account scope is everywhere (as shown) combined with the according scope.

Comment: @001 If you want seperate functionality for the account scope only, then you should use the lines as you've commented. Where account also has access to AccountRead and AccountWrite protected code.

Comment: If I do it your way, how come we would need "account" as a scope? why not just "account.read", "account.write", "account.delete" ?

Comment: just like this... options.AddPolicy("Account", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.read", "account.write", "account.delete"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountWrite", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.read", "account.write"));
options.AddPolicy("AccountRead", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account.read"));

Comment: the above policy for "AccountWrite" means it requires scope with "account.read" and "account.write" ? but why would "AccountWrite" policy require scope "account.read" ?

Comment: options.AddPolicy("AccountRead", policy => 
    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "account", "account.read")); <--- what does this actually mean? uesr must have both account and account.read scope to "read"? or mus thave both scope to "read"

Comment: @001 Scopes are _client_ claims, so we are talking about _client_ authorization here. When you decorate the _AccountController.Index_ method with an authorization attribute that requires the `AccountRead` policy then each _client_ that has either the `account` scope or `account.read` scope can access the method. Clients that are not allowed to request either one of these scopes can't access the resource. Without further additions this policy will allow any _user_ to access the resource. You can extend this with user authorization claims to narrow access or use resource-based authiorization.

Comment: You can think of the `account` scope as an 'admin' scope, meaning that all actions (CRUD) are allowed for any _client_ that is allowed to request this scope. While the `account.read` scope should be used for _clients_ that are allowed to read the resource only.